# How to reset an Int value on the database for every 24 hours?

Tags: java

I want to reset a value on the database for every 24 hours Automatically. I have an Int value on the database, and i want to set it to 5 for every 24 hours.

Comment: What flavour database is it?

Comment: And how is this related to Java? Do you use JDBC? JPA?

Comment: Why not just setting a scheduler inside your database?

Comment: Since the question is really vague, the answer has to be too... Make a script or application that accesses the SQL database and performs a query to set the value to 5. Then use cron (linux) or scheduled tasks (windows) to run that program every 24 hours.

Comment: It should be done by database, although if want to do it try Timer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to be resetted immediatly.
make a script. when you need the int and 24 hours is past reset it first before you use it.

then you don't need a script running in the background all the time.
Without a litle server running the script I doubt its even possible.

Answer (score 2):

Write a scheduler which will be executed on every 24 hr delay to execute the sql to set the value to 5.